# the return statement is not working

Tags: python

I am a python beginner and here I am stuck while trying to define the factorial function.
The problem is when I put print instead of return the function works perfectly, but unfortunately I need to use the factorial function in another function which means that I do  need the return statement.
anyways !(http://postimg.org/image/bgctbpi31/)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def fact(x):
  x=int(input("enter a number : "))
  result=1
  if x<0:
             print'it does not exist'
  elif x==0:
              return result
  else:
             for i in range (1,x+1):
              result=result*i
              return result

  return result
fact(5)
```

Comment: Code is text. Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and precise description of the problem **in the question itself** - offsite pictures are *not an acceptable way of providing code*.

Comment: def fact(x):    
  x=int(input("enter a number : ")) 
  result=1
  if x<0:
             print'it does not exist'
  elif x==0:
              return result
              
  else:
             for i in range (1,x+1):
              result=result*i 
              return result 
              
  return result
fact(5)

Comment: First of all - return statement is working correctly, you are just using it wrong. What are you trying to achieve? If you expect fact(5) to print the result on the screen - you are wrong, to do that you must write `print fact(5)`. Secondly - you are returning a result inside a loop, which stops your loop, just find someone else's `fact` function and see how it's done.

Comment: [**Edit the question.**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26993136/edit) Whitespace is important in Python, it's unreadable in comments.

Comment: Also, you should consider indenting your code properly. It's common practice to use 4 spaces per level. This increases readability and the change to find mistakes a lot.

Comment: I want the fucntion to return the result instead of printing it. the code above is not doing it!!

Comment: *"the code above is not doing it"* is **not** a useful problem statement - what output did you expect, and what do you get instead? Does it return nothing? The wrong answer? What have *you tried* to fix it? And, again, this should go **in the question**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simple enough problem, i would rekomend using recursion for it because its a recursive problem:

```
def nfak(n):
    if n < 0 :
        raise ValueError('Input has to be positive')
    elif n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * nfak(n - 1)
```

Comment: Although a working approach, this does not explain to the OP why their code did not work or how they could fix it.

Comment: and get a stack overflow, because python doesn't support tail recursion and this is not in tail-recursive form anyway.

Comment: Kinda a long way to go to get a stack overflow on most setups. Returning -1 shows that something whent wrong

Comment: @Svavelsyra no; in Python, *raising an error* shows that something went wrong.

Comment: @jonrsharpe true that, will edit

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there you have a return inside the for loop. You should take care with indentation, as Python uses indentations levels to determine scope.

```
def fact(x):
    r=1
    if x<0:
        print "does not exist"
        return None
    elif x==0:
        return r
    else:
        for i in range(0, x):
            r *= i+1
    return r
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to handle the functions out put as print are keeping in a variable as

```
def fact(x):
    x=input("input : ");
    result=1;
    if x < 0:
        return "no answer";
    elif x==0:
        return x;
    else:
        for i in range(1,x+1):
            result=result*i
        return result;
print fact(5);
```

This is working fine. as

```
stackoverflow$ python fact.py 
input : 5
120
```